# How to make rounded corner textview without xml in android?

Tags: android

I know how to make a textview with rounded corner using xml.
hundreds of colors have to be set as background color in rounded textview.

If 4 or 5 colors, it's fine but hundreds..

How can I make it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see GradientDrawable

Comment: Amazing!! Thanks @pskink  (min API 16)

Comment: what do you mean by "(min API 16"?

Comment: Forgot to mention. I used a method 'setbackground(drawable)'. this method requires min API 16.

Comment: Use then setBackgroundDrawable

Comment: setBackgroundDrawable() is used with API -16, setBackground() with API 16+